# Grails g:select add HTML 5 data attributes

Tags: html, grails

I want to load extra data into each select option of Grails `g:select` taglib. Required output is like the following:

```
<select id="select">
  <option value="1" data-foo="dogs">this</option>
  <option value="2" data-foo="cats">that</option>
  <option value="3" data-foo="gerbils">other</option>
</select>
```

I am not able to find a way to add the extra data to the taglib using the data attributes of HTML 5. So how to achieve the similar output?

Comment: Why don't you write a simple TagLib to achieve this?

Comment: The built in TagLib doesn't support this feature. If you need this then you'll have to implement your own.

Comment: Yes I did that only but came here to check if it exists or was there any shortcut. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: This is not possible. Yes, you have to create your own taglib

Answer (score 6):

You can do this by (mis-)using a closure to render the value (called optionKey in Grails select taglib) of the select options:

```
<g:select from="${books}"
      optionKey="${{ book -> "${book.id}\" data-author=\"${book.author.name}"}}"
      optionValue="title"
      name="selectedBook"/>
```

This will render the options with a `data-author` attribute:

```
<option value="1" data-author="Johann Wolfgang von Goethe">Faust</option>
```

This works at least in Grails 2.4.4 and Grails 3.1.5.

Comment: It looks like as of at least Grails 3.2.2 (I haven't gone back to look when the feature was introduced) the g:select tag now includes a dataAttrs attribute which allows you to add data-* to option values in a select tag.  Reference here:  http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Tags/select.html

Comment: This is nice.  Unfortunately, it uses the optionKey to decide if any option is selected, it wont take the value parameter into account. Too bad, it was a nice hack.

Answer (score 3):

The grails `<g:select />` tag now has the `dataAttrs` attribute that takes a map which is converted to data attributes as follows:

```
<g:select from="${dogs}" dataAttrs="[foo: it.species]" name="dog" />
```

if each dog has an attribute called species whose values are as presented in the question, this code would yield...

```
<select id="select">
  <option value="1" data-foo="dogs">this</option>
  <option value="2" data-foo="cats">that</option>
  <option value="3" data-foo="gerbils">other</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by the comments above this is currently not possible. You need to write your own tag library to achieve this goal.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve similar result using the following

```
<select id="select">
  <g:each in="${books}" var="book">
     <option value="${book.id}" data-foo="${book.slug}">${book.name}</option>
  </g:each>
</select>
```